# Hibernate persisting incorrect values

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have some Hibernate code running against a Postgres 9.5 DB, which looks like roughly like below (anonymized) -

```
Integer myEntityId = myEntity.getId();
getCurrentSession().evict(myEntity);
myEntity.setId(null);
MyEntity clonedMyEntity = (MyEntity)getCurrentSession().merge(myEntity);
myEntity.setMyBooleanField(false);
getCurrentSession().save(myEntity);
```

I have an entity myEntity with a large number of fields. I want to create a duplicate of the record with only 1 field value changed. To achieve this, I evict the entity from session, set Primary Key to null, merge it back to session, set the field I want to change, and then save the entity to DB. However, this code (which was working correctly for some time), is not working now. It sees incorrect value for the boolean field I am trying to modify - as a result violating some database constraints. Please help me fix this or suggest a better way to achieve what I am trying.

Comment: The error was happening not on adding this record but on add of another record to an audit table, triggered by the addition of this record. A coworker suggested me to use Eclipse Breakpoint view and use the add breakpoint option there and select the ConstraintViolationException class - this helped me to see the error for which trigger was failing and why.

Answer (score 0):

The error was happening not on adding this record but on add of another record to an audit table, triggered by the addition of this record. A coworker suggested me to use Eclipse Breakpoint view and use the add breakpoint option there and select the ConstraintViolationException class - this helped me to see the error for which trigger was failing and why and accordingly modify the data to suit the database constraint.